# Is there a way to include a "var" list in a place where JavaScript expects an expression?

Tags: javascript

The following code:

```
console.log((var a=5; ++a));
```

Does not compile, because `var` is considered a statement, not a function. The following does compile:

```
console.log((a=5, ++a));
```

And words as expected, outputting 6 - but it can polute the outside namespace. Is there any way to make the first snippet work, **without** introducing a closure, like below?

```
console.log((function(a){return ++a})(5))
```

This is for a compiler that targets to JavaScript, so your answer must respect the requeriments.

Comment: How about `console.log(6)` ?

Comment: How about `var a=5; console.log(a++)`?

Comment: What compiler if I may ask? Is an ES6 solution cool?

Comment: Those examples do, of course, output `5`, not `6`.

Comment: @JanDvorak the code must be inside `console.log(*)` because that is where the compiler will throw the code.

Comment: @Viclib ungh... why is the compiler doing that?

Comment: @JanDvorak ...? Because that is how it works, I want to have an expression such as `(def a 5)` without polluting the global namespace. So wherever that expression is thrown at on the resulting code, it must not destroy everything else. Wrapping a function around it seemed expensive, thus the question.

Comment: @Viclib: This compiler you're writing will need to have a broader understanding of the target context, rather than assuming it can create variables willy-nilly anywhere it wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, at least as of version 5.1 of the ECMAScript language specification current modern browser JS is based of, there.

When you do `console.log(` - what comes next is an [`ArgumentList`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.4).

Itself, it contains an [`AssignmentExpression`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13).

An Assignment Expression is:

> ConditionalExpression:
>
> LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression

A Conditional expression is a LogicalORExpression or a ternary, for completeness you are encouraged to [investigate this part further](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11) but they don't really help us (it describes how things like `a || 3` for example are defined, and bracnhes to things like `a && 6`).

Now, the other branch is `ConditionalExpressionNoIn` which is the ternary operator. (That is, ?:, the shorthand if). Which also, a short investigation can show us only runs expressions.

On the other side, [left hand side expressions](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2) allow function expressions, but nothing else that's really helpful for opening statements.

Now, on the other hand, a `var` appears in two places. In a [`VariableStatement`](http://es5.github.io/#x12.2), or in iteration constructs like for explicitly. Both of these in turn can not appear in the AssignmentExpression.

Thus, like the earlier answer suggests. **An implementation of JavaScript that abides to the specification, does not allow the sort of syntax you're asking for**. The [only expression](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2) in this list that allows statements inside it is indeed the function expression.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that without introducing a function. Simply declare your variable above the statement.